# How to put Wordpress manually onto Bitnami on local computer?

Tags: wordpress, bitnami

I use:

- Bitnami Wampstack 7.3.17-1
- Wordpress 5.4

What I want to do is installing Wordpress manually onto Bitnami on my local PC. I am familiar with XAMPP and WAMPP, so I though what I need to do after unzip the wordpress file is only to put it on **htdocs** folder. But I couldn't found it on Bitnami, what I can see is **apps** folder.

Then, because when I tried to access **phpMyAdmin** I only need to go to: **127.0.0.1/phpMyAdmin/**, I thought it will also work for the wordpress. But turns out it's not.

I don't want to use Bitnami-wordpress installer like **bitnami-wordpress-5.4.1-0-windows-x64-installer.exe**. Because in the future I want to do it for other php-based website I made.

Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Bitnami Engineer here, you can follow these steps to deploy a PHP application on top of WAMP:

- Copy the installdir/docs/demo folder into the installdir/apps directory.
- Add the following line to the end of the installdir/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf file:

> Replace the installdir placeholder with the full installation directory for your Bitnami stack.

```
Include "installdir/apps/demo/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
```

- Restart the Apache server using the graphical manager tool.
- You should now be able to access the demo application at http://localhost/demo. - You should see a “Hello world” message in your browser.
- You can now replace the files inside the installdir/apps/demo/htdocs folder with the WordPress' ones to deploy that application.

You can learn more about this here

https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/infrastructure/wamp/administration/create-custom-application-php/